# Radix Sort & O(N log N) Efficiency

Tags: sorting, big-o, radix-sort

I have been learning about Radix sort recently and one of the sources I have used is the Wikipedia page.  At the moment there is the following paragraph there regarding the efficiency of the algorithm:

> The topic of the efficiency of radix sort compared to other sorting
>   algorithms is somewhat tricky and subject to quite a lot of
>   misunderstandings. Whether radix sort is equally efficient, less
>   efficient or more efficient than the best comparison-based algorithms
>   depends on the details of the assumptions made. Radix sort complexity
>   is O(wn) for n keys which are integers of word size w. Sometimes w is
>   presented as a constant, which would make radix sort better (for
>   sufficiently large n) than the best comparison-based sorting
>   algorithms, which all perform O(n log n) comparisons to sort n keys.
>   However, in general w cannot be considered a constant: ***if all n
>   keys are distinct, then w has to be at least log n for a random-access
>   machine to be able to store them in memory, which gives at best a time
>   complexity O(n log n).*** That would seem to make radix sort at most
>   equally efficient as the best comparison-based sorts (and worse if
>   keys are much longer than log n).

The part in bold has regrettably become a bit of a block that I am unable to get past.  I understand that in general Radix sort is O(wn), and through other sources have seen how O(n) can be achieved, but cannot quite understand why n distinct keys requires O(n log n) time for storage in a random-access machine.  I'm fairly certain it comes down to some simple mathematics, but unfortunately a solid understanding remains just beyond my grasp.

My closest attempt is as follows:

Given a base, 'B' and a number in that base, 'N',  The maximum digits 'N' can have is:

> (logB of N) + 1.

If each number in a given list, L, is unique, then we have up to:

> L *((logB of  N) + 1) possibilities

At which point I'm unsure how to progress.

**Is anyone able to please expand on the above section in bold and break down why n distinct keys requires a minimum of log n for random-access storage?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming MSB radix sort with constant `m` bins:

- For an arbitrarily large data type which must accommodate at least `n` distinct values, the number of bits required is `N = ceiling(log2(n))`
- Thus the amount of memory required to store each value is also `O(log n)`; assuming sequential memory access, the time complexity of reading / writing a value is `O(N) = O(log n)`, although can use pointers instead
- The number of digits is `O(N / m) = O(log n)`
- Importantly, each consecutive digit must differ by a power-of-2, i.e. `m` must also be a power-of-2; assume this to be small enough for the HW platform, e.g. 4-bit digits = 16 bins

During sorting:

- For each radix pass, of which there are `O(log n)`:

  1. Count each bucket: get the value of the current digit using bit operations - `O(1)` for all `n` values. Should note that each counter must also be `N` bits, although increments by 1 will be (amortized) `O(1)`. If we had used non-power-of-2 digits, this would in general be `O(log n log log n)` ( [source](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12931/complexity-of-taking-mod) )
  2. Make the bucket count array cumulative: must perform `m - 1` additions, each of which is `O(N) = O(log n)` (unlike the increment special case)
  3. Write the output array: loop through `n` values, determine the bin again, and write the pointer with the correct offset

Thus the total complexity is `O(log n) * [ n * O(1) + m * O(log n) + n * O(1) ]` = **`O(n log n)`**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Regarding the 4th point, is that just a general comment?  As Radix sort doesn't do any comparisons as far as I know

Comment: @Levenal apologies, clearly `My_Brain.exe has encountered a problem and has to close`.

Comment: May I suggest a reboot =)  The edit was very helpful, thanks.  Breaking it down as you did is making it easier to work through.  I haven't grasped it all yet, but am more confident now in getting there.